# How to output (anything) if any error happens

Tags: programming, output-formatting, warning-messages, error-tracking

I have long code which goes through iteration process. some times I get error messages. 
I want to get the iteration numbers (or any kind of output indications) when errors happen.
for example, how can I print something when error happen in this simple example:

```
   Do[{i/i, 1/(i - 5)}, {i, -10, 10}]
```

here, there are two errors when i=0 & when i=5,

how can I output the values of i when the errors happen.

I have different kinds of errors so I want to get the output if any kind of error happen.

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Do[
  Check[{i/i, 1/(i - 5)}, Print@i],
  {i, -10, 10}] // Quiet
```

> 0
>
> 5

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
a = Table[{i/i, 1/(i - 5)}, {i, -5, 5}] // Quiet
```

> {{1, -(1/10)}, {1, -(1/9)}, {1, -(1/8)}, {1, -(1/7)}, {1, -(1/    6)},
>   {Indeterminate, -(1/5)}, {1, -(1/4)}, {1, -(1/3)}, {1, -(1/    2)},
>   {1, -1}, {1, ComplexInfinity}}

```
DeleteCases[a, {___, Indeterminate | ComplexInfinity, ___}]
```

> {{1, -(1/10)}, {1, -(1/9)}, {1, -(1/8)}, {1, -(1/7)}, {1, -(1/    6)},
>   {1, -(1/4)}, {1, -(1/3)}, {1, -(1/2)}, {1, -1}}

```
Position[a, #] & /@ {Indeterminate, ComplexInfinity}
```

> {{{6, 1}}, {{11, 2}}}